# Java libGDX will not draw sprites when the camera coordinates do not match the window coordinates

Tags: java, libgdx

I am having a problem with the libGDX engine. I have a pair of variables to set the width and height of the screen, and another pair to set the width and height of the camera. However, whenever the camera is not the same size as the screen, the engine will not render any sprites. Here is my code for you to look at:

My Constants:

```
public abstract class Constants 
{
    public static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;

    public static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 600;
}
```

Where the Sprite is Created:

```
public class GameController 
{
    public static final String TAG = GameController.class.getName();

    public Sprite[] testSprites;
    public int selectedSprite;

    public GameController()
    {
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        initTestObjects();
    }

    private void initTestObjects()
    {
        testSprites = new Sprite[1];

        int width = 32;
        int height = 32;

        Pixmap pixmap = createProceduralPixmap(width, height);

        Texture texture = new Texture(pixmap);

        for(int i = 0; i < testSprites.length; i++)
        {
            Sprite spr = new Sprite(texture);

            spr.setSize(32, 32);
            spr.setOrigin(spr.getWidth() / 2.0f, spr.getHeight() / 2.0f);

            spr.setPosition(0, 0);

            testSprites[i] = spr;
        }

        selectedSprite = 0;
    }

    private Pixmap createProceduralPixmap(int width, int height)
    {
        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, Format.RGBA8888);
        pixmap.setColor(1, 0, 0, 0.5f);
        pixmap.fill();

        pixmap.setColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
        pixmap.drawLine(0,  0, width, height);
        pixmap.drawLine(width, 0, 0, height);

        pixmap.setColor(0, 1, 1, 1);
        pixmap.drawRectangle(0, 0, width, height);

        return pixmap;
    }

    public void update(float deltaTime)
    {
        updateTestObjects(deltaTime);
    }

    public void updateTestObjects(float deltaTime)
    {
        float rotation = testSprites[selectedSprite].getRotation();
        rotation += 90 * deltaTime;
        rotation %= 360;
        testSprites[selectedSprite].setRotation(rotation);
    }
}
```

And the Drawing:

```
public class GameRenderer implements Disposable
{
    public static final String TAG = GameRenderer.class.getName();

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private GameController gameController;

    public GameRenderer(GameController gameController)
    {
        this.gameController = gameController;
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Constants.CAMERA_WIDTH, 
                                        Constants.CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        camera.update();
    }

    public void render()
    {
        renderTestObjects();
    }

    private void renderTestObjects()
    {
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();

        for(Sprite sprite : gameController.testSprites)
        {
            sprite.draw(batch);
        }

        batch.end();
    }

    public void resize(int width, int height)
    {
        camera.viewportWidth = 
            (Constants.CAMERA_HEIGHT / height) * width;

        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
        batch.dispose();
    }

}
```

The code above works fine and will render a sprite in the center of the screen, but when I change CAMERA_WIDTH and CAMERA_HEIGHT to say 80 and 60 respectively, instead of making the sprite 10x larger like it should, it doesn't draw anything. Any advice?

Comment: Is it just me, or do you not actually call the resize() at any point? I can see the resize() but can't see where it gets called? I'm maybe just missing the call..

Comment: resize() gets called automatically when the screen changes size, like if you hit the maximize button on the window or you stretch it.

Comment: really, I don't see any @Override annotation above the method or any listeners?

Comment: What about `camera.viewportHeight` it does not need update?

Comment: In that equation no, the idea is the height will always be the same number of world units, but it will show more/less of the world as the width changes in relation to the height.

Comment: @Smoggers Oh, sorry! It gets called externally, there is another class, but it doesn't do much beyond creating these classes here and running the rendering loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dividing ints by ints, so you end up with poorly scaled numbers. For example:

```
camera.viewportWidth = 
        (Constants.CAMERA_HEIGHT / height) * width;
```

If the screen width and height are 800 and 600, and `CAMERA_HEIGHT` is 60, then the equation becomes

```
camera.viewportWidth = 
        (60 / 600) * 800;
```

which becomes (due to pure integer math):

```
camera.viewportWidth = 
        (0) * 800;
```

which becomes 0. You need to cast those ints to floats before dividing! This may not be the only issue, but it alone could be causing your problem.

Comment: That fixed it! I can't believe I forgot about something so simple. Though the width worked fine, actually I think it was something internal to the camera that wasn't behaving right. Either way thanks a bunch!